# Why can't I trim a column of type CHAR?

Tags: oracle, trim

Like the title says, if a create a table in my DB :

**CREATE TABLE TEST
(
FIELD CHAR(20 CHAR) NULL
)
NOLOGGING
NOCOMPRESS
NOCACHE;**

Insert this :

**Insert into TEST
(FIELD)
Values
('TEST -here are blank spaces- ');
COMMIT;**

Then i run the following statement :

**UPDATE TEST SET FIELD = TRIM(FIELD);
COMMIT;**

but the field still has blank spaces, notice that if I change the data type to varchar2, it works ... does anyone know why?

Thanks!

Comment: because char datatype is for fixed length strings, so it will always have as many char as you specify in the DDL. Otherwise use varchar2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char` is a fixed width data type.  A `char(20)` will always and forever have a length of 20.  If you try to insert a shorter string, it will be padded with spaces to the fixed width length of the field.  So

```
UPDATE TEST SET FIELD = TRIM(FIELD);
```

removes the spaces due to the `trim` function, then adds them back because the string that gets written has to be exactly 20 bytes long.

Practically, there is almost never a case to use `char`.  You're almost always better off with a `varchar2`.  `varchar2` is a variable length data type so there is no need for the database to append the spaces to the end.

Comment: "Almost" in "almost never" is correct. When we tell beginners about this, it helps to give them examples of the exceptions (indicating that the exceptions are very few indeed). You might validly use `char(1)` for sex/gender columns, or yes/no ('Y'/'N') columns, or `char(2)` for U.S. state codes like CA, NY, FL. This is when the column is supposed to always store strings of pre-determined length; padding should (almost) never be something that actually comes into play.